# Pi got your number

Tags: code-golf, pi

### Challenge :

\$\pi\$ is supposed to be infinite. That means every number is contained inside the decimal part of \$\pi\$.
Your task will be to take a positive integer on input and return the position of this number in \$\pi\$ digits on output.

For example, if the input is `59`, we'll return `4`

**Here is why :** we will look for the number `59` in the digits of \$\pi\$

```
3.14159265...
     ^^
```

The value starts at the 4th digit, so the output will be `4`.

**Some other examples :**

```
input : 1      output : 1
input : 65     output : 7
input : 93993  output : 42
input : 3      output : 9
```

### Rules :

- You don't have to handle digits that doesn't exist within the first 200 digits
- Standard loopholes are, as always, forbidden.
- This is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf), so the fewer bytes wins.

Comment: Numbers with the property you mention are known as *normal numbers*. An infinite decimal expansion, even if non-periodic, doesn't imply normality. **0.101001000100001...** is a counterexample.

Comment: And, absolutely, Pi is *not* supposed to be infinite. It's decimal representation, however, have infinite digits.

Comment: @Dennis Normal is a much stronger condition (all-uniform vs all-exist)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85590/find-numbers-within-the-copeland-erdős-constant)

Comment: @user202729 Shows how much I know about number theory. :/

Comment: I was about to incorrectly type the same (numbers like that being _normal_) :-D

Comment: Can we take input as a string?

Comment: @Dennis yes, there is no restiction for the input

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/find-the-number-in-the-champernowne-constant)

Comment: Are we allowed to output the 0-indexed `n`'th index? So the text cases would return `0, 6, 41, 8` instead of `1, 7, 42, 9`.

Comment: @rafa11111 I agree. We should abandon integers and use numbers in base-PI. Then integers will have infinite digits, instead.

Comment: "You don't have to handle digits that doesn't exist within the first 200 digits" - do you mean *input integers* that don't?

Comment: @mbomb007 that's a lovely idea but, unfortunately, somebody already thought on this... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation#Base_%CF%80

Comment: @rafa11111 Yeah, I know. I've been looking at related information.

Comment: @rafa11111 https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/76062/34718

Comment: I say allow for negative numbers, with the understanding that negative means "signed" so it's the first occurrence of that number where it is immediately preceded by `1`.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number: **It is widely believed that** the (computable) numbers √2, **π**, and e **are normal, but a proof remains elusive**. (emphasis mine) π only _probably_ contains every possible sequence of digits.

Comment: I improved formatting, feel free to [take it back](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/8828) if you don't want it.

Answer (score 22):

## Python 2, <s>69</s> <s>75</s> <s>71</s> 67 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes due to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/390415?noredirect=1).*

```python
x=p=1333
while~-p:x=p/2*x/p+2*10**200;p-=2
print`x`.find(input(),1)
```

Not finding `3` at position zero cost <s>6</s> 2 bytes. Input is given as a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8K2wNbQ2NiYqzwjMye1TrfACiiib6RVoV@gbaRlaKClZWRgYF2ga2vEVVCUmVeSUJGgl5aZl6KRmVdQWqKhqWOo@f@/kqmlEgA)

---

**Unbounded Version**

### Python 2, 224 bytes

```python
def g():
 q,r,t,i,j=1,0,1,0,1
 while True:
  i+=1;j+=2;q,r,t=q*i,(2*q+r)*j,t*j;n=(q+r)/t
  if n*t>4*q+r-t:yield n;q,r=10*q,10*(r-n*t)
a=input()
l=len(`a`)
s=z=10**l;i=1-l
p=g().next;p()
while s!=a:s=(s*10+p())%z;i+=1
print i
```

Using an unbounded spigot based on the same formula used above.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc5LjsIwDAbgfU4RFiMlqTs0ZVaNzCk4AJUI4CoKaWrE4/KdBBa2ZPuz9KcXX2@xX9eTP8uL0oOQM2RgIJjQQgefEvJxpeDlId99EZIatG5qsHcfjLMhUL2Zm6zNBGwmF1HVactVn2U0vP@r95aHF/lwkrG@ou3MDKWp3BaixYgU052VFgGDj@o4HrVY8F2hCY7QtkEkLEF/o3@yS0V@oy0bHIcF1WJs15S1/nm7GlOkTJElravtd/8)

---

**Faster Version**

```python
from gmpy2 import mpz
def g():
  # Ramanujan 39, multi-digit
  q, r, s ,t = mpz(0), mpz(3528), mpz(1), mpz(0)
  i = 1
  z = mpz(10)**3511
  while True:
    n = (q+r)/(s+t)
    if n == (22583*i*q+r)/(22583*i*s+t):
      for d in digits(n, i>597 and 3511 or 1): yield d
      q, r = z*(q-n*s), z*(r-n*t)
    u, v, x = mpz(1), mpz(0), mpz(1)
    for k in range(596):
      c, d, f = i*(i*(i*32-48)+22)-3, 21460*i-20337, -i*i*i*24893568
      u, v, x = u*c, (u*d+v)*f, x*f
      i += 1
    q, r, s, t = q*u, q*v+r*x, s*u, s*v+t*x

def digits(x, n):
  o = []
  for k in range(n):
    x, r = divmod(x, 10)
    o.append(r)
  return reversed(o)

a=input()
l=len(`a`)
s=z=10**l;i=1-l
p=g().next;p()
while s!=a:s=(s*10+p())%z;i+=1
print i
```

A much faster unbounded spigot, based on [Ramanujan #39](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oSioAM4wORMC&pg=PA38&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLRjpswEHz3V2xVVbKNuWITciQR/Yiqb1WlQ7XJuQVDjEmT/Hy6BpI@VCB5dzzjnV17uIb33qn7vfF9B8duuCqw3dD7AN1wI9o0cKRsTwA@wte6q930q3aQ7wR0Uxtsqu3RBtw9CfACRhABqqikGRPzmheqXEO5rhlDgUWexPW28mXGOM8LGbE/77Y18M1PJhYGcMihp8Szz3RMApsx20QYcaWKMueWL/uPLPIWMUDTe9BgHcxmR@oE2C/F7hVqpyGWBCRItoerNa0GvcpiS1j4xukpdXxE8xh6DFcHk4CzgMvD/7O5R7PkUft3rO1rdzS02G2ftn4K0AIa1FtO5z9X6aZkiVIszQUoudlm3KYqy/NXAanl8VObcpcX23I95J@JieOBdOI6OTPeIMablWMhWWb9vCYB8ZpOHNUnfk48vyAYsxGzwC9kvvh1XLjnZtM9ar7/IP815daWLsvAtD13vY4ymS1D6F/qYTBOUx9zb8LkUWvOxo9G054RUlfWDVOgjLRVaxx9q98YGatbJTPO24OtZNqSocKn@OLMJRwGZC6vZPxQ1fuxoiOXWYIw@3Q72KSSZPDWBbD3u1T5pvgL)

Comment: Nice, neither hardcodes nor use built-in (because Python doesn't have any)

Comment: This fails for input `3` (expected 8, but outputs 0). You need to ignore the `3` before the decimal comma.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen missed that, thanks.

Comment: I think you are allowed to remove the `+1` and output the 0-indexed result, but not sure. I've asked OP to clarify, since I do the same in my Java answer.

Comment: [Trivial 4 byte reduction](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8K2wNbQ2NiYqzwjMye1TrfACiiib6RVoV@gbaRlaKClZWRgYF2ga2vEVVCUmVeSUJEQbWgVq5eWmZeikZlXUFqioampbfj/v5KppRIA)

Comment: @Dennis 31 needs to match at 137 :/

Comment: Which approximation algorithm is this? Is it one listed here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

Comment: @Sphinxxx it's the resullt of apply the Euler transform to the Leibniz series. I've posted a derivation in [a previous post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18988/4098).

Answer (score 19):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
€tİπd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTmpIjG843pPz//9/S2NLSGAA)

#### Explanation

```
€tİπd                              59
    d  Convert to base-10 digits   [5,9]
  İπ     The digits of pi          [3,1,4,1,5,9..]
 t       Remove the first element  [1,4,1,5,9,2..]
€      Index of the sublist        4
```

Comment: Ridiculous - but I have to admit I'm impressed.

Comment: With golfing languages it's usually a good idea to add an explanation, since someone who doesn't know the language won't be able to read it. If I understand correctly it's: Take the index of (`€`) with the first item (the leading 3) removed (`t`) of the digits of PI (`İπ`), convert it to base-10 (`d`) and output to STDOUT (implicitly).

Comment: Agreed, I have no idea what I'm looking at.

Comment: Is `İπ` a lazy representation of the digits? Otherwise, whats the precision?

Comment: @gggg looks like it is a lazy representation [example](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTmpIjG843pPz//9/QyBgA), [verification](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWPeqY@mtMEYkzb7vdo/rJHnVMDMg9PP99@vu3R/OWHdv7/b2hkDAA)

Comment: @gggg `İπ` is an infinite list of digits, created with an unbounded spigot [source](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/blob/0806b9db5681ee9ba1eea9f90bfe86a8e35d8fe0/intSeq.hs#L59)

Answer (score 18):

## Excel, 212 bytes

```
=FIND(A1,"14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196")
```

Excel only handles 15 decimal places so pi is just hard-coded. This should be a pretty weak upper bound for this challenge.

Comment: I'm sorry to comment on my own post, but can some of the upvoters tell me why they like this answer? It's as golfed as it can be in an Excel formula but it's very long and not at all clever.

Comment: I like this because it doesn't rely on golfing languages which have builtins to calculate pi to an arbitrary decimal place.  It may not be creative, but it's practical (not that practicality matters here).

Comment: As the question doesn't specify that the input or answer *have* to be base 10, could you golf this by using [`CONCAT`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) and a [BBP formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) to calculate the first 200 digits of π-base16 and search in Hexadecimal instead?  (Don't have 365, so can't test)

Comment: Office 365 only: using `CONCAT`, `CODE` and `MID` I reduced the PI string from 202 characters (inc quotes) to 143: `CONCAT(CODE(MID(".ÜÁ£ÙÏ ¦®š«¦ Ï²œÔ“ÇÅ§ÝËŠº”á±¬»—‡ÑÀ†œ¾ˆãÖœƒ°™¢•‘†ÏÒŽÐÖ³ ÒžÂ¯‰¦¬¼ß²º–ŸÈµ»¨Ñœ°‹‘­‚ÔŠ›ÝÕ•Š·»À®–ÞÙ¶ÝƒÑà",2*ROW(A1:A100)-1,2))-32)`

Comment: @Chronocidal That's impressive but I can't verify that in Excel Online, which is all I can access. Does it need to be entered as an array formula? That would explain it because Excel Online doesn't allow entering array formulas. If you post yours as a separate answer, I'll definitely vote for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also can't properly verify it (I tested by using 100 rows and `CONCATENATE(A1,A2,A3..A100)` o_O), but [the examples](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) on Office.com seem indicate that it doesn't need to be entered as an array formula...  **Can anyone with Office365 either disprove or confirm & post as an answer?**

Comment: Testing with Office365, it looks like it outputs 14 regardless of the input?

Comment: @MatthewSchlachter Thanks for testing! :)  Sounds like it's only processing the first character though...  :(  If you press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to turn it into an Array Formula, does it still give `"14"`, or output all 200 digits?

Comment: @Chronocidal - your discussion on this made me want to try a whole bunch of string compression methods for this, [so I did - link.](https://gist.github.com/Taylor-Alex-Raine/f3475f858d59c79316f1ab710d09a700) I found that for this case, sticking to ASCII-only compression is preferred for this problem, and found four equivalent 148 byte solutions that you can see in Approach 5. I also found two 96 char, 177 byte solutions using triple byte unicode characters.

Answer (score 9):

## Java 8, <s>615</s> <s>217</s> <s>202</s> <s>184</s> <s>182</s> <s>166</s> 165 bytes (calculated <s>999</s> 200 digits)

```java
n->{var t=java.math.BigInteger.TEN.pow(200);var r=t;for(int p=667;p-->1;)r=t.valueOf(p).multiply(r).divide(t.valueOf(p-~p)).add(t).add(t);return(r+"").indexOf(n,1);}
```

1-indexed

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZBPS8QwEMXv@ymGnhK0YeviSgndg@DBg/Ww3sRDbNKamqYhnVaXpX71mu4f8CILE4bM@/GYN7UYRFzLz6kwouvgSWi7XwBoi8qXolCQz9/DAAqyRa9tBZbyMBzDC9WhQF1ADhYymGy82Q/CA2Z1cGaNwA92r6vH4Fcpz14ecubaL3KzXFI@cz5DXraezP4uW6/vuIvjTcJpENggTK@eS@Ioa3qD2pkd8ZRJPWipyB89/nGUMiElwXPjXmHvLfFXUUSZtlJ9B9JeJ5SPEz@u7vp3E1Y/JRhaLaEJBzjFfH0DQY/pt7sOVcPaHpkLEhpLLCtIlET0cIr/ifXtRSRdpenqInUmxsU4/QI)

Java's builtin `Math.PI` has a precision of 15 decimal values, like many other languages. To have more digits, you'll have to calculate them yourself with `BigIntegers` or `BigDecimals`. This above is a way to do it.. <s>Maybe someone can golf this below 211 bytes, lol..</s>
EDIT: Created a port of [*@primo*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161164/52210) (make sure to upvote him!), so calculating being shorter than hard-coded is not so far-fetched anymore. <s>Just 7 more bytes to golf for it to be shorter.</s>

-15 bytes thanks to *@Neil*, making it shorter than the hard-coded answer below!
-36 bytes thanks to *@primo*.
-1 byte changing `java.math.BigInteger t=null,T=t.TEN.pow(200),r=T;` to `var T=java.math.BigInteger.TEN.pow(200);var r=T;`, because `var` is 1 byte shorter than `null` (gotta love the new Java 10).

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                            // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  var t=java.math.BigInteger.TEN.pow(200);
                                //  Temp BigInteger with value 10^200
  var r=t;                      //  Result BigInteger, also starting at 10^200
  for(int p=667;                //  Index-integer, starting at 667
      p-->1;)                   //  Loop as long as this integer is still larger than 1
                                //  (decreasing `p` by 1 before every iteration with `p--`)
    r=                          //   Replace the Result BigInteger with:
      t.valueOf(p)              //    `p`
       .multiply(r)             //    multiplied by `r`,
       .divide(t.valueOf(p-~p)) //    divided by `2*p+1`
       .add(t).add(t);          //    And add 2*10^200
  return(r+"")                  //  Convert the BigInteger to a String
    .indexOf(n,                 //  And return the index of the input,
               1);}             //  skipping the 3 before the comma
```

---

## Java 8, 211 bytes (hard-coded 200 digits)

```java
"14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196"::indexOf
```

0-indexed

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZBNbgIxDIX3nCKaFSyKbMdObFCPULpgWXUxHQY0FAJiBtSq4uzT8NNlhZQosvM@W@@ty1P5tF589tWmbFv3UjbpZ@Bck7r6sCyr2s0u5bXhquG8OzRp5dJompvnfPNpu7JrKjdzyT27vkBGMQriRS2aJ68cKLD36imaAKkyWsRg3sxHQRAlsMjGnEEPUTEwBNJAoGb5UfCsJJ4JMUKIpoSsoEHQk2YkBI5geRMHMJHLRPIYMyLGoEjKipnly3pGoAiY5ZLngYhYyCCRsZqwefCKForJpEmL@ut12U9vRvfHj002evd72jULt81x3UN5e3fl6JbV/Lvt6u14d@zG@/zVbdIwjathgcXoGtz/iiAPJdfYHqr@FOfBuf8F)

Comment: `!p.equals(t.ONE)` perhaps? Also, `indexOf(n,1)-1` works I think. Or save 2 bytes and make it 1-indexed.

Comment: Not sure how I missed the first, but the second I really need to remember. Didn't knew there was an `indexOf` method that skips the first `m` characters. TIL, thanks!

Comment: How about [keeping p an integer](https://tio.run/##hZA/T8MwEMV3PsUpk0@0pkkEUmXCgMTAQBmaDTGY2C0ujmMll5CqymcP7h9EF1Tpbri73z3pvY3s5HSjvsbCyqaBF2nc7grAONL1ShYaFvvxsICCLak2bg0ORVgOoUM1JMkUsAAHGYxu@rDbBE1eSvrkj2b9HJTWugbKXGvtJM@Id9K2@nXFEpz0WS5WVc328j6L0zQV8b0Xfpol2J@h/iZBXraWjLdb1iNXpjNKszMCkUulWP6HEc@fFtxX3yyZzRBR1Jra2rH@OoqQG6d0Hx7dJEYxjOLoxrcfNrg5meoqo6AMmZycv72DxGMgy21DuuRVS9yHE1nHHC9YFEd4SOd/4u72IjJP5/P0IvVLDFfD@AM "Java (JDK 10) – Try It Online")?

Comment: @primo Thanks! 18 bytes saved thanks to you! (After your port already saved about 400 bytes.. ;p)

Comment: You can also decrement `p` by one each time (`for(int p=667;p-->1;)`), and then multiply by `p` and divide by `p-~p`.

Comment: If you redefine `T` as `t.TEN.pow(200)`, then you can just `.add(T).add(T)`.

Comment: @primo But how about `r=T`? `r` should start at `2`, shouldn't it?

Comment: The initial value of `r` can literally be anything, although extreme values will require more iterations. The best seed (fewest iterations) is actually `4e200`.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
YP8WY$4L)jXfX<q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzLAIjxSxcRHMysiLcKm8P9/S2NLS2MA)

#### Explanation

```
YP     % Push pi as a double
8W     % Push 2^8, that is, 256
Y$     % Compute pi with 256 significant digits using variable-precision arithmetic
       % The result as a string
4L)    % Remove first character. This is to avoid finding '3' in the integer part
       % of pi
j      % Push input as a string
Xf     % Strfind: gives array of indices of occurrences of the input string in the
       % pi string
X<     % Mimimum
q      % Subtract 1. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Very nice and short ! Can you explain how it works ?

Comment: @Therandomguy Sure, explanation added

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
₁žs¦¹k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UVPj0X3Fh5Yd2pn9/78xAA)

**How?**

```
₁        push 256
 žs      push pi to 256 places
   ¦     remove the leading 3
    ¹    push the input
     k   index inside that string
```

Comment: If I get the similar 6-byte solution in the same language, after you, do I delete my answer?

Comment: @nicael usually it doesn't matter, but your solution fails for `3` anyway

Comment: Oh, indeed, thnks

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + numbers package, 52 bytes

```r
regexec(scan(),substring(numbers::dropletPi(200),3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyg1PbUiNVmjODkxT0NTp7g0qbikKDMvXSOvNDcptajYyiqlKL8gJ7UkIFPDyMBAU8dYU/O/8X8A)

`dropletPi` computes the first 200 decimal digits of `pi` but includes a `3.` at the beginning, so we strip that out with `substring` and then match with `regexec`, which returns the index of the match along with some metadata about the match.

Comment: Maybe `regexpr(scan(),numbers::dropletPi(200))-2`?

Comment: @djhurio that doesn't work because we have to match in the digits after the decimal point. That was my first thought as well but that case ruins it. Maybe an `"if"`?

Comment: I do not see a problem here. Non of the input will contain `3.` (I assume we deal with integers not reals in input). The test examples work with this.

Comment: @djhurio right but `regexpr(3,numbers::dropletPi(200))-2` returns `-1`  when it should return `9`, [try it](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyg1PbWioEijODkxT0NTJ680Nym1qNjKKqUovyAntSQgU8PIwEBTU9fov/F/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁵*⁹Ḥ;ȷḊ+J$¤×⁹:2¤:ɗ\SṾḊw
```

A monadic link accepting a list of characters (the integer to find) and returning the index. Works for inputs contained within the first 252 digits of the decimal part of π.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R41atR407H@5YYn1i@8MdXdpeKoeWHJ4OFLIyOrTE6uT0mOCHO/cBJcr///@vbmlsaWmsDgA)**

#### How?

This uses the [Leibniz formula for π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) to calculate the first 253 digits including the leading `3` (plus four trailing incorrect digits). The leading `3` is then dropped and the index of the input is found:

```
⁵*⁹Ḥ;ȷḊ+J$¤×⁹:2¤:ɗ\SṾḊw - Link: list of characters
⁵                       - literal ten
  ⁹                     - literal 256
 *                      - exponentiate = 10000...0 (256 zeros)
   Ḥ                    - double       = 20000...0
          ¤             - nilad followed by links as a nilad:
     ȷ                  -   literal 1000
      Ḋ                 -   dequeue -> [2,3,4,5,...,1000]
         $              -   last two links as a monad:
        J               -     range of length -> [1,2,3,4,...,999]
       +                -     addition (vectorises) -> [3,5,7,9,...,1999]
    ;                   -   concatenate -> [20000...0,3,5,7,9,...,1999]
                  \     - cumulative reduce with:
                 ɗ      -   last three links as a dyad:
               ¤        -     nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
            ⁹           -       chain's right argument (the right of the pair as we traverse the pairs in the list -- 3, 5, 7, 9, ...)
              2         -       literal two
             :          -       integer division (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ...)
           ×            -     multiply (the left of the pair, the "current value", by that)
                :       -   integer divide by the right argument (i.e. 3, 5, 7, 9, ...)
                   S    - sum up the values (i.e. 20000...0 + 66666...6 + 26666...6 + 11428...2 + ... + 0)
                    Ṿ   - un-evaluate (makes the integer become a list of characters)
                     Ḋ  - dequeue (drop the '3')
                      w - first (1-based) index of sublist matching the input
```

If you prefer a list of digits as input use `⁵*⁹Ḥ;ȷḊ+J$¤×⁹:2¤:ɗ\SDḊw` (also 23), while if you really want to give it an integer use `⁵*⁹Ḥ;ȷḊ+J$¤×⁹:2¤:ɗ\SDḊwD` (for 24).

Comment: You mean Euler's transform applied to the Leibniz formula. Calculating 252 digits with the Leibniz formula would take a wee bit longer than most people would be willing to wait.

Comment: Yes it would take a long time in raw form (it's still "using the Leibniz formula" I believe!)

Answer (score 3):

## BASH (GNU/Linux), <s>75</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to Sophia Lechner, and 7 bytes thanks to Cows quack.

```
a=`bc -l<<<"scale=999;4*a(1)"|tail -c+2|grep -ob $1`;echo ${a%%:*}
```

This is a shell script that takes a single argument, which is the number. Test with

```
$ bash <script-path> 59
4
```

This script first executes a pipeline of three commands:

```
bc -l<<<"scale=999;4*a(1)"|    #produce pi with its first 999 fractional digits
tail -c+2|                     #cut off the "3."
grep -ob $1                    #compute the byte offsets of our argument in the string
```

The result of this pipeline is assigned to the shell variable `a`, which is then echoed out with anything but the first number removed:

```
a=`...`;         #assign the result of the pipeline to a variable
echo ${a%%:*}    #cleave off the first : character and anything following it
```

---

Unfortunately, `bc` has the tendency to break output lines when they become too long. This may lead to wrong results if the number to be found is not on the first line. You can avoid that by setting the environment variable `BC_LINE_LENGTH`:

```
export BC_LINE_LENGTH=0
```

This deactivates the line breaking feature completely.

---

Obviously, the last two commands may be omitted if other output is tolerated.
This gives a count of **48 bytes**:

```
bc -l<<<"scale=999;4*a(1)"|tail -c+2|grep -ob $1
```

With the resulting output:

```
$ bash <script-path> 59
4:59
61:59
143:59
179:59
213:59
355:59
413:59
415:59
731:59
782:59
799:59
806:59
901:59
923:59
940:59
987:59
```

Comment: Nice! You don't need that space between `-l` and `<<<` though.

Comment: You can convert to a program and use sed to save some bytes, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PylZQTfHxsZGqTg5MSfV1sjAwNpEK1HDUFOppiQxM0dBN1nbqCa9KLVAQTc/SUHFsKY4NUWhWN9KT0tf/////5bGlpbGAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @Cowsquack Wouldn't I need to include a shebang line in the byte count then?

Comment: @cmaster shebang lines are not included in byte counts for any languages

Comment: @Cowsquack Thanks for the suggestion. However, if you allow for additional output, you might as well leave out the `sed` as well (see the second part of my answer). Nevertheless, transforming to a program gave me 7 bytes, so thanks for that! I have also replaced the `tr`/`head` combo with shell variable magic now to save another byte.

Comment: @SophiaLechner Cool, I would not have thought that's possible. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. I had to look up `bc` to figure out what it was and also that `a` is the arctan function.

Comment: @gggg Yeah, `bc` is one of those really powerful tools with a rather retro-charm to them that are usually overlooked completely. Today, one would probably name that `a()` function just `arctan()`, but that would have cost me another five bytes...

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>208</s> 120 bytes

```hs
a=1333
x=tail$show$foldr(\p x->p`div`2*x`div`p+2*10^200)a[3,5..a]
x!n|take(length n)x==n=0|1<2=1+tail x!n
f n=1+x!show n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc3LTsMwEAXQvb/iJsqiD1rFNgVFwixgWUQrsUHioVjEbqIaJ2pcMFK/HeNmFVYzczRzp5b9XhkTghSUc068cLIxWV@335luTXWYvHbwi9uurJqvks38ULs5m9H8neX5VL7wi9VyKd@IT@zJyb2aGGV3roadeiGsyE/0hgk6P@ci7hANG0efnH/ABo8ydkdT3akSPxDoju7JHR4sMjQaHkJEdrWySDfrFMr0Culj67BZJykhn7Kx8apqCaBBx2l0oKvV2K4HK3hR8DFfssH/WRF@P7SRuz4snu@32z8)

<sup>Many thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) for his suggestions!</sup>

#### Old version (208 bytes)

```hs
(+1).((tail$g(1,0,1,1,3,3))!)
g(q,r,t,k,n,l)=([n:g(10*q,10*(r-n*t),t,k,div(10*(3*q+r))t-10*n,l)|4*q+r-t<n*t]++[g(q*k,(2*q+r)*l,t*l,k+1,div(q*(7*k+2)+r*l)(t*l),l+2)])!!0
x!n|take(length n)x==n=0|1<2=1+tail x!n
```

I actually don't know how the code above works; I've taken it from [this paper](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf) and all I implemented was the lookup part.
`g(1,0,1,1,3,3)` returns the digits of pi and is surprisingly efficient (it computes 10 000 digits on tio.run in less than 4s).

The input is a list consisting of the digits of the number to be found.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDLasMwEEX3/oqxyUIvF8tOG1yiTbtMaQLZFNxATCM/sKrUtlJcyLfXHQcCjQYNzD33DkhV3jfamLFQ7yPhkt4R4vLazEoiRSQkViISSn3qlaQVnXCiEVYYqkhmH9EUsVZgI11omaMXfKi/J50krOUdpS7EYYqc55MQuiU6d5xnuJA1gsQXGzPC4W24vORbRhas4THlHTOUIKLC4Lijvh95g2/PLm80MdqWrgJLB6Wsis5yGSvJpwcAesYB9n11PJnDk97DDyj4Ormt614szKAuYAClUHaVthCsVwFo02sIXo8O1is/8LzPvLaYOhw9wFNAJnf/N8qr/CDub8DiClL8vRQrucHz@Mpv9XT8/ShMXvZj@Pa82fwB)

Comment: My guess is that  the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) will be far shorter.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks! I will give it a try. I absolutely love this site! I've learned *so much* from you, guys! :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I tried to approximate pi using `l=4*sum[((-1)**x/(2*x+1))|x<-[0..1e6]]`, but that takes 5s to run and the 7th digit is already wrong. So it might not be feasible to compute 200 digits. It was an interesting exercise anyway, so thanks!

Comment: You'd want to use the Euler transform (see my Jelly answer or primo's Python answer)

Comment: In reference to the paper you linked, you might be interested in [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85409/4098), in which I re-implement the code found in this paper without "deliberate obfuscation." It's also quite a bit simpler (shorter) as a result. See method `g1_ref` in section _Faster Unbounded Generators_. The code is python.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, <s>179</s> 164 bytes

```
INPUT I$FOR I=0TO 103Q$=Q$+STR$(ASC("\A#YO &.+& O2TGE']KiRa1,;N(>VYb>P0*uCb0V3 RB/]T._2:H5;(Q0oJ2)&4n7;@.^Y6]&"[I]))NEXT?INSTR(Q$,I$)+1
```

Digits of pi are hardcoded and packed into the ascii values of characters.
14 -> `CHR$(14)`, 15 -> `CHR$(15)`, 92 -> `\`, 65 -> `A`, 35 -> `#`.

The string contains unprintable characters, so here are the bytes written in hexadecimal: `0E 0F 5C 41 23 59 4F 20 26 2E 1A 2B 26 20 4F 32 1C 54 13 47 45 27 5D 4B 69 52 00 61 31 2C 3B 17 00 4E 10 28 3E 56 14 59 62 3E 50 03 30 19 03 2A 75 00 43 62 15 30 00 56 33 20 52 1E 42 2F 00 5D 54 2E 00 5F 32 3A 16 1F 48 35 3B 28 51 1C 30 6F 4A 32 1C 29 00 1B 00 13 26 34 6E 37 3B 40 2E 16 5E 59 36 5D 00 26 13 06`

In decimal, you can see the digits of pi: `14 15 92 65 35 89 79 32 38 46 26 43 38 32 79 50 28 84 19 71 69 39 93 75 105 82 0 97 49 44 59 23 0 78 16 40 62 86 20 89 98 62 80 3 48 25 3 42 117 0 67 98 21 48 0 86 51 32 82 30 66 47 0 93 84 46 0 95 50 58 22 31 72 53 59 40 81 28 48 111 74 50 28 41 0 27 0 19 38 52 110 55 59 64 46 22 94 89 54 93 0 38 19 6`

Comment: If you post the complete code, it would make it easier to verify your answer.

Comment: I can't post it because there are invalid characters that are removed/not displayed. I guess I can post the ascii codes though.

Comment: You could post a hexdump, using xxd for example.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>186</s> 177 bytes

```
`nqnrvosrpruvtvpopuqsosqppÕÝvr¶uuqnvtnsvpvvptrnmruomvtqvqqrvopmÉæqÛàÑ$vvÔàmpqupqm¡vuqum«rnpopmssqtmvpuqqsmvrrmruoopÌÊprvqÛ$uqunnqr¶uqn¶tmnvpÔnmrrrvsqqsoovquvrqvpmpunvs`®c -#mÃbU
```

Since Japt shares Javascript's 15-digit Pi constraint and [shoco](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/), the encoding used by Japt, doesn't encode numbers, some shenanigans are required for compression.

Shortly explained, the beginning is the below string in encoded form:

```
"nqnrvosrpruvtvpopuqsosqppupotvrmouuqnvtnsvpvvptrnmruomvtqvqqrvopmtunsqmsousomuvvusoumpquorpqonntmstvuonqumusrnpouopmssqtmvpuqqsmvrrmruoopntorprvqmunouqunnntqrmouqnmotmnvpuronnmrrrvsqqsoovquvrqvpmpunvs"
```

Which is a string where each letter is `'m' + corresponding digit of pi`. I tested the whole alphabet and that letter gives the best compression by a few bytes.

Backticks tell Japt to decode the string. The rest of it is pretty straightforward:

```js
®c -#mÃbU
®          // Given the above string, map each letter
 c         // and return its charcode
   -#m     // minus the charcode of 'm', 109.
      Ã    // When that's done,
        bU // find the index of the implicit input U.
```

Outputs 0-based index of the matching fragment.
Shaved another two bytes off thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY09ToJBEIavQiKtFY0XoUftSGZ23pmd9wJWEhsTrAgJNDQmlhxg52CfS//87F@tL8tOoc4Wbp7stGaJaAGz@qkzfdwzoewaNNK6q3g2YQeBKZrUZ91Qp7rU95qsY13EkAYZVyZSxq/rzEoEunDmEUL3R6ZZfdXBnNNfT1YVjyF03LsorY7z5s6YTmtE0kETS2Xsxt/76vlJ6uNtuyybzcs/)

Comment: Clever idea! You can replace `£X` with `®` and `} ` with `Ã`

Comment: @Oliver Thanks a lot for those, I'm still learning Japt so all help is very appreciated.

Comment: You've been doing great so far! I was curious to see if there was a better offset than 109. [I made a bruteforcer](https://tio.run/##Fc29SgNxEATw3qdYrlLS7PfudL6BoAgBERFNFImXHF6bZ4//VNPMb@bn/bReLtNhN3@t30TH/f5vt95MG2U@Ft@/PHzcPi/0@zbTZkufZ1ru6EBPp6Dt60Jnmml5HFxcApph0SiYWntqulmbFoK12wUlCQOsQjhaGeVwH9C4WtI5tVO5gRHN5q1hriLFWWgVb@4MMe1BMr0Y48mTEXFdVJMaJODcou0tw/r13oW1WEY9xh5HBHJAVXgjHMbWgpz@AQ), and it turns out 109 is optimal. Nicely done :)

Comment: @Oliver Thanks for that, I simply tried the whole a-z range manually since it wasn't too much work. :P

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>197</s> 187

<sup>-10: Thanks, [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!</sup>

```
x=>"50ood0hab15bq91k1j9wo6o2iro3by0h94bg3geu0dnnq5tcxz7lk62855h72el61sx7vzsm1thzibtd23br5tr3xu7wsekkpup10cek737o1gcr6t00p3qpccozbq0bfdtfmgk".replace(/.{9}/g,a=>parseInt(a,36)).search(x)+1
```

Takes a series of nine-digit base-36 integers, converts them to base 10, and concatenates them to create the first 200 digits of pi.

Comment: Nice, you blow my attempts at encoding the data out of the water, your approach saves 38 bytes on the raw data.

Comment: +1 - I was about to post the exact same approach.

Comment: Use `x=>'50...'.replace(/.{9}/g,a=>parseInt(a,36)).search(x)+1` to save 10 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>27</s> 15 bytes

```
Ｉ⊖∨⌕Ｉ▷N⟦≕Piφ⟧θχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyU1uSg1NzWvJDVFw79Iwy0zLwUi4VqWmFOaWJIalliUmZiUk6qh5KekoxDtnlqCEAnIVNLUUTA0MDCI1QQyCsEcTSCw/v/f@L9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Works up to nearly 1000 digits. Explanation:

```
        ≕Pi     Get variable `Pi`
           φ    Predefined variable 1000
     ▷N⟦    ⟧   Evaluate variable to specified precision
    Ｉ           Cast to string
             θ  First input
   ⌕            Find
              χ Predefined variable 10
   ∨             Logical OR
  ⊖              Decrement
 Ｉ               Cast to string
                 Implicitly print
```

Comment: [fixed, 13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyU1uSg1NzWvJDVFwy0zLwUi6lqWmFOaWJIalliUmZiUk6qh5KekoxDtnlqCEAnIVNLUUTA0MDCI1QQyCjWBwPr/f0tjS0vj/7plOQA). side note: this feels really cheaty :P

Comment: [actually fixed, 13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWPeqY@mtMEYkzb7vdo/rJHnVMDMs@3PZq//NDO//8tjS0tjQE). uses implicit input. (not intended behavior but it seems more useful than any other way). also could you link to an example of the fill bug?

Comment: @ASCII-only [Fill weirdness](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJSknTmss3vyxVw9BAR8HKJzWtBCiALOmWmZOjoaSnBBe20LT@/9/S2NLS@L9uWQ4A "Charcoal – Try It Online") - why does the cursor end up there?

Comment: :| oh i have no idea i should fix that asap

Comment: [nvm i'm an idiot](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/blob/eae1ef9b6ddd59286678c0cf4c7336f3dc5bc31f/charcoal.py#L1616), committed fix.

Comment: [this will work after Dennis pulls](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/985sbhEwy0zL0UjOCczOVUDzHctS8wpTSxJDUssykxMyknVUPJT0lGIdk8tQYgEZCpp6igYGhgYxGqCGJqamv//WxpbWhr/1y3LAQA)

Answer (score 2):

First time doing code golf. Use delegates and lambda expressions to reduce the function calls. V2 shorten class name into a single byte.

## [C#], <s>361</s> 355 bytes

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){Func<string,int>F=f=>"14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196".IndexOf(f)+1;Action<int>w=Console.WriteLine;w(F("1"));w(F("65"));w(F("93993"));w(F("3"));}}
```

**Formatted version:**

```
using System;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<string,int>F=f=>"14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196".IndexOf(f)+1;
        Action<int>w=Console.WriteLine;
        w(F("1"));
        w(F("65"));
        w(F("93993"));
        w(F("3"));
    }
}
```

[Ideone!](https://ideone.com/xMp2Kg)

NB.I miscounted the first version. It was 361 bytes, not 363 bytes.

## [C#], tio version 218 bytes

```
f=>"14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196".IndexOf(f)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBSsNAEIbP5imWnBLUsjM7sztDbS9CQVAUPHgOaVoCbQLZVJTSZ4/bonjsXGYYvu8fmDre17GeDrHttub9O47Nfp5l9a6K0bwN/Xao9tkxM6niWI1tbT77dm1eqrYrysv6mN2sDl39EMchRdy13bg0K7OYNotlDgSs6NmxaFCHTsijJ@fEYVC2KEKgAbw6VRcYLAtaDaRESXQ2CHiyHsWjFdXUxDoSZEcIEKwPKggkVjyDQ0mK9xSspkvkrTKfE9FBSAorWQEUEkgunc8TWAwWEs4pzzKz@iQiKokyqbNOQH0@e@rWzdfrptiUtzCZ35pnf9Nj38V@18w@hnZsntuuKVZFDnlZXkE8X2cuv7mO/SOn7DT9AA)

Comment: You don't need to include the test cases in your code, and you can just use a lambda (anonymous) function instead of a full program

Comment: [Hyarus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79576/hyarus) suggested `using System;f=>"14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196".IndexOf(f)+1;` as an edit.

Comment: I'm new here and I thought I must include a full program including the test case. It seems people are using tio.run for demonstration instead of ideone. I see that tio.run divide the code into parts.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```ruby
p"#{BigMath::PI 200}"[3..-3]=~/#$_/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BJudopM903sSTDyirAU8HIwKBWKdpYT0/XONa2Tl9ZJV7//39LY0tL43/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzipIy01NSkzNzE3P0c4E6AQ)

Nothing special, just showcasing the built-in library. Output is 0-indexed.
The Pi string is formatted as `0.31415...e1`, so we need to strip off the first 3 chars. The `e1` part in the end doesn't really do any harm, but it is stripped off too, as we need to provide a range end (or slice length) value anyway.

Comment: short AND readable!

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 230 bytes

Using laziness to find the number anywhere in the infinite digits of pi, not just in the first 200 digits. Oh yeah, and it returns you every (infinitely many?) instance(s) of the number, not just the first one.

```
p=g(1,0,1,1,3,3)where g(q,r,t,k,n,l)=if 4*q+r-t<n*t then n:g(10*q,10*(r-n*t),t,k,div(10*(3*q+r))t-10*n,l) else g(q*k,(2*q+r)*l,t*l,k+1,div(q*(7*k+2)+r*l)(t*l),l+2)
z n=[(i,take n$drop i p)|i<-[1..]]
f l=[n|(n,m)<-z$length l,m==l]
```

### Examples from the challenge

```
>  take 10 $ f [1]
[1,3,37,40,49,68,94,95,103,110]
>  take 10 $ f [6,5]
[7,108,212,239,378,410,514,672,870,1013]
>  take 1 $ f [9,3,9,9,3]
[42]
>  take 10 $ f [3]
[9,15,17,24,25,27,43,46,64,86]
```

### Credits

'p' is the infinite stream of pi digits, taken from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pi#Haskell

```
> take 20 p
[3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9,7,9,3,2,3,8,4]
```

Comment: I guess you already know this, but you only need to output the first number in your sequence...

Comment: Just thought I'd embrace the infinite-ness :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
ȷ*
ȷR×¢:Ḥ‘$ƲU×:¢+¢ʋ/ḤṾḊw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9qZWxsef//yLcqCsi3UsOXwqI64bik4oCYJMayVcOXOsKiK8Kiyosv4bik4bm@4biKd////yc2NSc)

<s>Use a [Machin-like formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Machin-LikeFormulas.html), specifically 1/4 pi == tan<sup>-1</sup>(1/2) + tan<sup>-1</sup>(1/3).</s>

Use the formula pi/2 == 1 + 1/3 × (1 + 2/5 × (1 + 3/7 × (1 + 4/9 × ( ... ))))

Comment: Is there a way to get digits from `ØP` in M?

Comment: @dylnan [Somewhat](https://tio.run/##y/3//8R2QwOTw9MPzwh4uGPe//8A "M – Try It Online"), but M is not Jelly.

Comment: I know they're different. Can't believe I didn't think of `floor`. Mind if I use that to post as answer in M?

Comment: Nevermind. [Doesn't work above 104 digits](https://tio.run/##y/3//8R2QwPTw9MPzwh4uGPe//8A)...

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) -M , <s>131 119</s> 117 bytes

Uses `-M` flag for arbitrary precision calculations.
Added `p=k=0` (5 bytes) to the TIO link to allow multi-line input

```
{CONVFMT="%.999f";PREC=1e3;for(p=k=0;k<1e3;)p+=(4/(8*k+1)-2/(8*k+4)-1/(8*k+5)-1/(8*k+6))/16^k++;$0=$1==3?9:index(p,$1)-2}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/2tnfL8zNN8RWSVXP0tIyTck6IMjV2dYw1dg6Lb9Io8A229bAOtsGxNcs0LbVMNHXsNDK1jbU1DWCsEw0dQ0hLFM4y0xTU9/QLC5bW9taxcBWxdDW1tje0iozLyW1QqNARwWkudbw/39DBTDILy0pKC1RsFIw5DIzRRUx57I0trQ0RhIxMeIyRtNmyfUvv6AkMz@v@L@uLwA)

**Explanation:**

```
{CONVFMT="%.999f";  # Allows 999 decimal digits to be used when numbers are convert to strings
PREC=1e3;           # Digits of precision to use for calculations
for(;k<1e3;)p+=(4/(8*k+1)-2/(8*k+4)-1/(8*k+5)-1/(8*k+6))/16^k++; # The most concise numerical calculation I could find. It doesn't converge  extremely rapidly, but it seems to work OK
$0=$1==3?9:index(p,$1)-2}  # Replace input line with either 9 or index-2
                           # since indices will either be 1 (meaning 3 was input) or >= 3
1                   # Print the "new" input line
```

Comment: My first attempt used `sprintf` to get the decimals.  Using `CONVFMT` is definitely cleaner.

Comment: No need to use the flag: [meta consensus is to consider this a language distinct from AWK](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/67312), "AWK with `-M` flag"

Comment: Good to know. I guess I should spend more time on meta... with my loads of free time. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2 <s>239</s> <s>238</s> <s>229</s> 214 bytes

*-9 bytes due to [@primo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4098/primo)*

```
from bigfloat import*;a=s=n=10**10**5;b=k=0
while a:k+=1;a*=k*(k*(108-72*k)-46)+5;a/=k**3*(640320**3/24);s+=a;b+=k*a
with precision(10**7):print`(426880*sqrt(10005*n)*n)/(13591409*s+545140134*b)`.find(input())-16
```

Uses the Chudnovsky-Ramanujan algorithm to find the first <s>1 million digits</s> 50000 digits of π (change `10**10**5` to `10**10**6` for more, but it takes ages to run) and then searches them for the desired string.

Comment: I tried to confirm the result but it doesn't seem to terminate (`n=10**10**5` takes about 10s).

Comment: @primo I never said it was fast! `10**10**6` takes about 7 minutes on my machine.. To be fair, `10**10**5` gives the first 50000 digits, so I guess it's not that bad either :)

Comment: @primo I've changed the arbitrary precision library to bigfloat, it runs much quicker now.

Comment: It's much faster now, I was going to suggest switching to `gmpy2`, but `bigfloat` saves a dozen or so bytes. The assignment of `k` can be merged with `k=b=0` if you move `k+=1` to the start of the iteration. `-(6*k-5)*(2*k-1)*(6*k-1)` can be written more succinctly as `k*(k*(108-72*k)-46)+5`. If you declare Python 2, the `//` integer divisions can be replaced by `/`, and also parentheses aren't necessary for `print`. Space can also be removed in `import*`. Only validates to 50000 digits, btw.

Comment: The `n` in `sqrt(10005*n)` seems to be the problem; it's moving the decimal point to 50000th place. In case you're interested, here's my own Chudnovsky implementation: [Try it online!](https://bit.ly/2IxenGy)

Comment: @primo Thanks! I did try `gmpy2`, but like you say, the program was 2 bytes longer. The 301000 figure was when using `gmpy2`, but since I'm using `bigfloat`, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript 217 bytes (200 hardcoded)

```
a=>"14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196".search(a)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### PHP, 27 bytes

<sup>Not a very serieus answer, it requires a change in the php.ini settings as pi() defaults to 14 digits, not 200, but for once the PHP solution is fairly elegant:</sup>

```
<?=strpos(pi(),$_GET[n])-1;
```

Comment: I don't think this will actually work. the `precision` tag in php.ini only alters the display precision, and doesn't actually increase the precision of defined constants. [witness](https://tio.run/##LY69DoIwGEV3nqLDR9ryI1gYDAU7mTiY6G6EGFqgC22A0We3lsT13nNurp2sc7UI9Ky7VW0E20X1etVmxglieU55oPrJIKsJTdDj@ugu9xtH4hwUh1oMZiEcRgGyyT8E3k8YXw3ICMY0zVj8T0TFaAhjdFQlzfaqYsWpru2i520goAQO81LiCuMEVAzSM22zwy0ov@ZVTrlzX2M3/2t16fwD)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 53 bytes

```julia
setprecision(9^6)
x->searchindex("$(big(π))","$x",3)
```

Set the precision for BigFloats high enough, then convert `pi` to a string and search. Precision of `9^6` handles 159980 digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctLCsIwEADQtTlFGFpIYFxIaCALxXv4gX6SOCLTklaYpTf0SNG3f8/3i3pf03GImbiucVtKHGmlmU24e6tkf1pjX8YH8RTFQGMGyub7sRYQGgF0tkaeVJqLFk2sLwf0HXYBgwvBobup3XkpxFsy0Pqs23xlQMFkxFr1r/UH)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 25 Bytes

```
{.I.(}.":<.@o.10x^999)E.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1@hWs9TT6NWT8nKRs8hX8/QoCLO0tJS01WvTkHdEgzU//8HAA)

0-Indexed

Takes input as a string, +2 Bytes (`":`) if that's not allowed.

Explanation eventually.

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) with `-MMath::BigFloat+bpi` and `-n`, 20 bytes

```perl
bpi($>)=~/.$_/;say@-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@pIFNDxU7Ttk5fTyVe37o4sdJB9/9/Qy4zUy5LY0tLYy5jLgtDSy4zExOjf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDYC0b2JJhpWVU2a6W05@Yok20LD/unk5AA)

I'm not sure where usage of `$>` stands, since it's the `EFFECTIVE_USER_ID` which is not portable, but on TIO this is 1000 and satisfies our requirement, for -1 byte vs. `200`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
€tİπd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTmpIjG843pPz//9/S2NLSGAA)

```
€        The 1-based index as a substring of
    d    the decimal digits of
         the input
  İπ     in the infinite list of digits of pi
 t       after the radix point.
```

Comment: [lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161193/80214)

Comment: @Razetime lmao, even

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) (ES2020), 75 bytes

```javascript
n=>`${eval(`for(a=c=2n*10n**300n,d=1n;a*=d;)c+=a/=d+++d`)}`.search("."+n)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCsMgEADQu4Qu1Gmt1pWEyVkc/PSDjEFLNqFnt@996KAR@3v/3rilPAtOxi1cznxQFaG0LggjPlhZw0o5Y/ia0PJKCtMqIyDdMQFACvIX9MjU40ssegGWYGdsPFrNuranKMI7752U8w8)

Uses the formula I've used in another Pi-related challenge. `search("."+n)` is needed to drop the leading `3`. Change `300` to a higher number gives more precision.