# One-to-one correspondence between pairs of integers and the positive integers

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, grid, open-ended-function

It is well-known that there are one-to-one correspondences between pairs of integers and the positive integers. Your task is to write code defining such a correspondence (by defining a pair of functions/programs that are inverses of each other) in your programming language of choice, plus a correctness check (see below) with the smallest number of bytes for the correspondence definition (not taking the correctness check into account).

The solution must include :

- the definition of a function/program f having two integer arguments and returning an integer (that's one direction of the bijection).
- either the definition of a function/program g having one integer argument and returning a pair of integers (might be an array, a list, the concatenation of the two integers separated by something   ...) or two functions/programs a and b having an integer argument and returning an integer (that's the other direction).
- an additional code snippet checking that for the f and g (or f and a,b) you defined above, you have g(f(x,y))=(x,y) (or a(f(x,y))=x and b(f(x,y))=y) for any integers x,y in the range -100 < x < 100,-100 < y < 100. Note that f and g have to work for values outside of this range as well.

You may rename a,b,f or g of course. The two solutions do not have to be written in the same language.

Below is a not-optimal-at-all solution in PARI/GP, with 597 characters for the function definitions.

```
plane_to_line(x,y)={
my(ax,ay,z);
ax=abs(x);
ay=abs(y);
if((ax<=ay)*(y<0),        z=4*y*y-2*y+x+2;);
if((ax<=ay)*(y>=0),       z=4*y*y-2*y-x+2;);
if((ay<=ax)*(x<0),        z=4*x*x    -y+2;);
if((ay<=ax)*(x>=0)*(y<0), z=4*x*x+4*x+y+2;);
if((ay<=ax)*(x>=0)*(y>=0),z=4*x*x-4*x+y+2;);
if((x==0)*(y==0),z=1;);
return(z);
}


line_to_plane(z)={
my(l,d,x,y);
l=floor((1+sqrt(z-1))/2);
d=z-(4*l*l-4*l+2);
if(d<=l,x=l;y=d;);
if((l<d)*(d<=3*l),x=2*l-d;y=l;);
if((3*l<d)*(d<=5*l),x=(-l);y=4*l-d;);
if((5*l<d)*(d<=7*l),x=d-6*l;y=(-l););
if((7*l<d)*(d<8*l) ,x=l;y=d-8*l;);
if(z==1,x=0;y=0;);
return([x,y]);
}
```

and the correctness-check code :

```
accu=List([])
m=100;
for(x=-m,m,for(y=-m,m,if(line_to_plane(plane_to_line(x,y))!=[x,y],\
listput(accu,[x,y]);)))
Vec(accu)
```

Comment: [We've already done the second part of this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48705/8478) but I guess the fact that both functions need to be each other's inverse might be sufficient interaction to justify [a multi-part challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8463/8478).

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'm not sure independent multi-part works. Part of the challenge is to pick the encoding that gives you the shortest functions.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I might be misunderstanding you, but I think that's what I said?

Comment: Can we provide only one program which can be called both ways?

Comment: I find the way this challenge is written overly technical and confusing. You will lose some people by using words like bijection, where one-to-one correspondence would do. I'm not sure what `Z^2` means. on googling I found `Z` to be the integers, so `Z^2` would be the square numbers. But you seem to mean a tuple of two integers. Please clarify the spec, perhaps with examples. Note that your own code is not a spec. The spec should be in English, with your code only to support it.   Also, does the checking function count as part of the codegolf score? if so, why?

Comment: @Fatalize sure, but I presume that would make your byte count higher

Comment: @LevelRiverSt The notation `Z` refers to a set of numbers, but `Z^2` refers to a set constitued of pair of numbers in `Z`. You could represent in your mind by oposing `Z`(or `Z^1`) as a 1-dimension environment (a *line*), and `Z^2` as a 2-dimension environment. `Z^n` is a `n`-dimension environment. It means that for every single point in one of these environment, there's an unique correspondant in each of the other ones. that's what this challenge is about ;)

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I think Fatalize was suggesting to count the program that can do both things only once.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt To supplement Katenkyo's comment, the reason `Z^n` stands for `n`-tuples is that the omitted operator isn't (pairwise) multiplication but the Cartesian product. `Z^2 = ZxZ`.

Comment: The test that g(f(x, y)) = (x, y) for all x, y is not sufficient to guarantee that f and g define a one-to-one correspondence. Counterexample in Python 2:
`f=lambda*l:int(repr(l).encode('hex'),16);g=lambda n:eval((len('%x'%n)%2*'0'+'%x'%n).decode('hex'));r=range(-100,101);assert all(g(f(x,y))==(x,y)for x in r for y in r)`

Must it also be true that f(g(n)) = n for all n? Should you require a check for this?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg No test on a finite set can ever show one-to-one correspondance. I might have included a requirement test for $f(g(n))=n$ but I didn't.

Comment: Finiteness is not the point. One can satisfy g(f(x, y)) = (x, y) for _all_ (x, y) as long as f is merely injective (as in my example); it need not be bijective. Do you require that f(g(n)) = n for all n is true, even if you don’t require a test for it?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Yes, $f(g(n))=n$ is expressed by the expression "one-to-one correspondence" even though I don't require a test for it as you say

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>43</s> 36 bytes

This uses the `spiral` (`1YL`) function, which generates a square 2D array of given size with values arranged in an outward spiral. For example, with input `7` it produces

```
43 44 45 46 47 48 49
42 21 22 23 24 25 26
41 20  7  8  9 10 27
40 19  6  1  2 11 28
39 18  5  4  3 12 29
38 17 16 15 14 13 30
37 36 35 34 33 32 31
```

The center of the array, which contains `1`,  corresponds to the tuple `[0 0]`. The upper left corner corresponds to `[-3 -3]` etc. So for example *f* (-3,-3) will be 43 and *g* (43) will be [-3 -3].

The code generates a 2D array with this spiral matrix, as large as needed to do the conversion. Note that larger sizes always give the same result for the entries already included in smaller sizes.

#### From **Z**<sup>2</sup> to **N** (18 bytes):

```
|X>tEQ1YLGb+QZ}3$)
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=fFg-dEVRMVlMR2IrUVp9MyQp&input=WzMgLTVd)

```
|X>   % input is a 2-tuple. Take maximum of absolute values
tEQ   % duplicate. Multiply by 2 and increase by 1. This gives necessary size of spiral
1YL   % generate spiral
G     % push input 2-tuple again
b+Q   % bubble up, add, increase by 1. This makes the center correspont to [0 0]
Z}    % split tuple into its values
3$)   % use those two value as indices into the spiral array to obtain result
```

#### From **N** to **Z**<sup>2</sup> (<s>25</s> 18 bytes)

```
Eqt1YLG=2#fhw2/k-q
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=RXF0MVlMRz0yI2ZodzIvay1x&input=MTAz)

```
Eq      % input is a number. Multiply by 2, add 1. This assures size is enough and odd
t1YL    % duplicate. Generate spiral of that size
G=      % compare each entry with the input value
2#fh    % 2-tuple of row and column indices of matching entry
w2/k-q  % swap. Offset values so that center corresponds to [0 0]
```

#### Snippet for checking

Note that `G` needs to be modified to accomodate the fact that we have don't have a single input. The code is slow, so the link checks tuples with values from -9 to 9 only. For -99 to 99 just replace the first line.

The code tests each tuple with values in the defined range. It does the conversion to a number, then from that number back to a tuple, and then checks if the original and recovered tuple are equal. The results should all be `1`, indicating that all comparisons give `true`.

It takes a while to run.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=LTk6OQpIWl4hIkAKfFg-dEVRMVlMQGIrUVp9MyQpClhKCkVxdDFZTEo9MiNmaHcyL2stcQpAIVg9&input=)

```
-9:9                     % Or use -99:99. But it takes long
HZ^!"@                   % Cartesian power: gives tuples [-9 -9] ... [9 9].
                         % For each such tuple
|X>tEQ1YL@b+QZ}3$)       % Code from Z^2 to N with `G` replaced by `@` (current tuple)
XJ                       % Copy result into clipboard J
Eqt1YLJ=2#fhw2/k-q       % Code from N to Z^2 with `G` replaced by `J`
@!X=                     % Compare original tuple with recovered tuple: are they equal?
```

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 171 bytes

```
(x,y)=>(h=x=>parseInt((x^x>>31).toString(2)+(x>>>31),4),h(x)*2+h(y))
x=>(h=x=>parseInt(x.toString(2).replace(/.(?!(..)*$)/g,''),2),i=x=>x<<31>>31^x>>>1,[i(h(x>>>1)),i(h(x))])
```

Bit twiddling: negative numbers have their bits flipped; each integer is then doubled, and 1 added if it was originally negative; the bits from the integers are then interleaved. The reverse operation deletes alternate bits, divides by 2, and flips all the bits if the value was negative. I could save 3 bytes by limiting myself to 15-bit values instead of 16-bit values.

```js
f=(x,y)=>(h=x=>parseInt((x^x>>31).toString(2)+(x>>>31),4),h(x)*2+h(y))
g=x=>(h=x=>parseInt(x.toString(2).replace(/.(?!(..)*$)/g,''),2),i=x=>x<<31>>31^x>>>1,[i(h(x>>>1)),i(h(x))])
for(i=-100;i<=100;i++)for(j=-100;j<100;j++)if(g(f(i,j))[0]!=i||g(f(i,j))[1]!=j)alert([i,j])
```

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, <s>50</s> <s>48</s> <s>46</s> <s>45</s> <s>43</s> <s>40</s> 39 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

### Plane to line (<s>18</s> <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)):

```
AḤ_<0$
+RS+
,Ñç/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QeG4pF88MCQKK1JTKwosw5HDpy8&input=&args=MQ+LTE)

### Line to plane (<s>32</s> <s>30</s> <s>29</s> <s>27</s> <s>24</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)):

```
HĊN⁸¡
³R‘R’U⁹¡F³ịÇ
ç1,¢
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=SMSKTuKBuMKhCsKzUuKAmFLigJlV4oG5wqFGwrPhu4vDhwrDpzEswqI&input=&args=Nw)

### Explanation:

I'll only explain `plane to line`, because `line to plane` is just its opposite.

Firstly, we convert each integer to a natural number, by the function `f(x) = 2*|x| - (x<0)`.

Then, we convert the two natural numbers to another two natural numbers, by the function `g(x,y) = (x+y,y)`.

Finally, we convert them into one natural number, by the function `h(x,y) = (x+1)C2 + y`

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, and now the try-it-online links' input is `7`

Comment: This looks better :-) I assume you are working on the checking snippet

Comment: @LuisMendo Does the checking snippet count towards the score?

Comment: No, the challenge says _not taking the correctness check into account_