# Determine the position of a non-negative number in the infinite spiral

Tags: code-golf, number

## Definition

The infinite spiral used in this question has `0` on the position `(0,0)`, and continues like this:

```
16-15-14-13-12
 |           |
17  4--3--2 11
 |  |     |  |
18  5  0--1 10
 |  |        |
19  6--7--8--9
 |
20--21...
```

It is to be interpreted as a Cartesian plane.

For example, `1` is on the position `(1,0)`, and `2` is on the position `(1,1)`.

## Task

Given a non-negative integer, output its position in the spiral.

## Specs

- Your spiral can start with `1` instead of `0`. If it starts with `1`, please indicate so in your answer.
- Output the two numbers in any sensible format.

## Testcases

The testcases are 0-indexed but you can use 1-indexed as well.

```
input output
0     (0,0)
1     (1,0)
2     (1,1)
3     (0,1)
4     (-1,1)
5     (-1,0)
6     (-1,-1)
7     (0,-1)
8     (1,-1)
9     (2,-1)
100   (-5,5)
```

Comment: Some bigger testcases would be nice.

Comment: @orlp Done.  –  –

Comment: Can we print coordinates as a complex number?

Comment: @orlp As long as it matches the regex.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the regex requirement for return values. In some languages, the output of, e.g., a complex number, will depend on what function is called to print it.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48705/8478)

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and 1j**int((4*n-3)**.5-1)+f(n-1)
```

[Dennis's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87185/20260) suggested the idea of summing a list of complex numbers representing the unit steps. The question is how to find the number of quarter turns taken by step `i`.

```python
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

These are generated by `int((4*k-n)**.5-1)`, and then converted to a direction unit vector via the complex exponent `1j**_`.

Comment: Just keep this answer since you two came up with it independently...

Comment: Doubly awkward... I independently discovered it. But I guess your chat message was first, so no way to prove it.

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 53 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(1j**int((4*i+1)**.5-1)for i in range(n))
```

Comment: Just keep this answer since you two came up with it independently...

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> <s>16</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḷ×4‘Æ½’ı*S
```

This uses the quarter-turn approach from [@xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87188)/[@orlp's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87187) answer.

Indexing is 0-based, output is a complex number. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bi2w5c04oCYw4bCveKAmcSxKlM&input=&args=MTAw) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bi2w5c04oCYw4bCveKAmcSxKlMKMTDhuLY7MTAwwrU7IsOH4oKsRw&input=).

#### How it works

```
Ḷ×4‘Æ½’ı*S  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

Ḷ           Unlength; create the range [0, ..., n - 1].
 ×4         Multiply all integers in the range by 4.
   ‘        Increment the results.
    Æ½      Take the integer square root of each resulting integer.
      ’     Decrement the roots.
       ı*   Elevate the imaginary unit to the resulting powers.
         S  Add the results.
```

Comment: At which point will you rename Jelly to 'random noise'?

Comment: Right after all other esolangs do the same. It's only noise if you don't understand it.

Comment: @orlp But Jelly is the one that looks the most like semi-random (emphasis on AltGr and punctuation modifier keys) hammering of a US International keyboard...

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>72</s> 62 bytes

```python
n=2;x=[]
exec'x+=n/2*[1j**n];n+=1;'*input()
print-sum(x[:n-2])
```

*Thanks to @xnor for suggesting and implementing the quarter-turn idea, which saved 10 bytes.*

Indexing is 0-based, output is a complex number. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/EHfyPJ).

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>57</s> 55 bytes

This is a simple implementation based on [Dennis's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87185/47581). Thanks to Doorknob for his help in debugging this answer. Golfing suggestions welcome.

```ruby
->t{(1...t).flat_map{|n|[1i**n]*(n/2)}[0,t].reduce(:+)}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```ruby
def spiral(t)
  x = []
  (1...t).each do |n|
    x+=[1i**n]*(n/2)
  end
  return x[0,t].reduce(:t)
end
```

Comment: Do you need the second pair of parentheses?

Comment: @LeakyNun Over `n/2`. I think so. Otherwise it tries to divide the array by 2 instead of multiplying by `n/2`. I'll see what I can do about it.

Comment: I don't think you need `flat_map` when regular `map` works just as well on ranges. Also, `[0,t]` gets you the same entries from an array as `[0...t]`

Comment: See here for the discussion about `flat_map` http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31403761#31403761. Thanks for the `[0,t]` tip.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES7), 75 bytes

```
n=>[0,0].map(_=>((a+2>>2)-a%2*n)*(a--&2?1:-1),a=(n*4+1)**.5|0,n-=a*a>>2)
```

Who needs complex arithmetic? Note: returns `-0` instead of `0` in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 135 bytes

```
@set/an=%1,x=y=f=l=d=0,e=-1
:l
@set/ac=-e,e=d,d=c,n-=l+=f^^=1,x+=d*l,y+=e*l
@if %n% gtr 0 goto l
@set/ax+=d*n,y+=e*n
@echo %x%,%y%
```

Explanation: Follows the spiral out from the centre. Each pass through the loop rotates the current direction `d,e` by 90° anticlockwise, then the length of the arm `l` is incremented on alternate passes via the flag `f` and the next corner is calculated in `x,y`, until we overshoot the total length `n`, at which point we backtrack and print the resulting co-ordinates.