# Given a grid, starting at the center and spiraling out, and an ID what is the Position?

Tags: code-golf

#### Grid:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  20       | id:  19       | id:  18       | id:  17       | id:  16       |
| pos: (-2, -2) | pos: (-1, -2) | pos: (0, -2)  | pos: (1, -2)  | pos: (2, -2)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  21       | id:  6        | id:  5        | id:  4        | id:  15       |
| pos: (-2, -1) | pos: (-1, -1) | pos: (0, -1)  | pos: (1, -1)  | pos: (2, -1)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  22       | id:  7        | id:  0        | id:  3        | id:  14       |
| pos: (-2, 0)  | pos: (-1, 0)  | pos: (0, 0)   | pos: (1, 0)   | pos: (2, 0)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  23       | id:  8        | id:  1        | id:  2        | id:  13       |
| pos: (-2, 1)  | pos: (-1, 1)  | pos: (0, 1)   | pos: (1, 1)   | pos: (2, 1)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  24       | id:  9        | id:  10       | id:  11       | id:  12       |
| pos: (-2, 2)  | pos: (-1, 2)  | pos: (0, 2)   | pos: (1, 2)   | pos: (2, 2)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

#### Challenge:

Given a grid, starting at the center and spiraling out, and an ID what is the Position in the fewest number of bytes?

```
f(0) = [0, 0]
f(2) = [1, 1]
f(5) = [0, -1]
f(14) = [2, 0]
f(24) = [-2, -2]

f(id) = [x, y]
```

#### Notes:

- Grid will always be `N x N` in size
- Position `x` and `y` are `int32` in size
- `id` is always `>= 0`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125966/wind-me-a-number-snake?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @user202729 - updated.

Comment: What is `N`, and how is that important? I think the grid is infinite?

Comment: This is a good challenge, but I think we've had it already: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/87178/20260

Comment: @xnor - Bummer. I searched but didn't find that. The only difference is how the spiral is wound up.