# Given a grid, starting at the center and spiraling out, and an Position what is the ID?

Tags: code-golf

**Related:**

- [Determine the position of a non-negative number in the infinite spiral](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87178/determine-the-position-of-a-non-negative-number-in-the-infinite-spiral)
- [Wind me a number snake!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125966/wind-me-a-number-snake?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Challenge:**

Given a grid, with an ID starting at the center and spiraling out, what is the ID given a position in the fewest number of bytes?

**Grid:**

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  20       | id:  19       | id:  18       | id:  17       | id:  16       |
| pos: (-2, -2) | pos: (-1, -2) | pos: (0, -2)  | pos: (1, -2)  | pos: (2, -2)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  21       | id:  6        | id:  5        | id:  4        | id:  15       |
| pos: (-2, -1) | pos: (-1, -1) | pos: (0, -1)  | pos: (1, -1)  | pos: (2, -1)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  22       | id:  7        | id:  0        | id:  3        | id:  14       |
| pos: (-2, 0)  | pos: (-1, 0)  | pos: (0, 0)   | pos: (1, 0)   | pos: (2, 0)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  23       | id:  8        | id:  1        | id:  2        | id:  13       |
| pos: (-2, 1)  | pos: (-1, 1)  | pos: (0, 1)   | pos: (1, 1)   | pos: (2, 1)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  24       | id:  9        | id:  10       | id:  11       | id:  12       |
| pos: (-2, 2)  | pos: (-1, 2)  | pos: (0, 2)   | pos: (1, 2)   | pos: (2, 2)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**Tests:**

```
f(0, 0) = 0
f(1, 1) = 2
f(0, -1) = 5
f(2, 0) = 14
f(-2, -2) = 20

f(x, y) = id
```

#### Notes:

- Grid will always be square (height == width)
- Grid can be infinite in size

Comment: How can the grid be both square and infinite in size?

Comment: Sorry, just trying to say it can be bigger than the example grid provided.

Comment: Sorta odd you chose to make the bottom right 1,1 and the top left -1,-1. Then again I guess Java does this in `java.awt.*`

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn - makes you think a little more? It's just the grid setup I've been using in my codebase. I didn't want to use the same old grid in my game.

Comment: The last case should output `20`,  not `24`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 64 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(x)(y)`.

```js
x=>y=>(d=(A=Math.abs)(A(x)-A(y))+A(x)+A(y))*d+(d-x+y)*(-y>x||-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxNCoMwEAXgvadwOWMYTaRdJpAD9BCp0f4gpjRSEvDuaWpLoRbewIOPeVfzML67X24zTc72aZApSBWlAitBy4OZz7U5egQNAUlDRGSvytZaWQaWAotYAUUVloUEps5N3o19PboTDMAxB8umKXnxKwJzVmmLvx/60H5D7XdO7DZE2fK9F3l6Ag)

Heavily inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2639611) from math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 58 bytes

```javascript
y=>x=>(m=Math.max)(4*x*x-m(x+y,3*x-y),4*y*y+m(-x-y,x-3*y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczdCoMwDAXge5/Cy6Y2WrW7rG@whyhO94O1MmWkT9@FbQzm4AQSPnJu7uHW/n5dNpzDaUijTdF2ZDvh7dFtl9I7AmEkSUIvqIiq5S2CMjLKWHiBfCnCVkaA1Id5DdNQTuEsRqGBA3lV5Tr7lRo4L2myvx/80GFHzbeuNjtCNp53o05P)

Use the formula from [my previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154458), with some edit (because Javascript doesn't vectorize).

I came up with the formula myself. Basically, knowing that the formula must be quadratic in each 1/4 grid section, I find out the formula mostly by trial-and-error and then find a way to fit those together.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
|sQtE1YLqwG+X{)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6Y4sMTVMNKnsNxdO6Ja8///aCMFg1gA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D/Cq6Y4sMTVMNKnsNxLO6Ja879LyP9oAwWDWK5oQwVDIGmgoAuijMBCukYKukaxAA).

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 37 bytes

```
(g@[-+<.-+[+[)>.(g=:4**:)@]-+>.]+]+-~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY2xCsMgFEV3v@LRRY2opbSLGMnSrv2A4JBITJSioTrn19NSQpc7HDjnjkNZ9vUdUvWAfaswGFhFiAW5oYLWcH8@wBxsJ3PXc6YFZz3rqRFkbtW1aRTtLGdGWGYZ3/avgia3ZMC/JbrzpzOVG7nwLYgbxf8gknmtMsoxJBldTiW/puPqAw)

My first J answer! Use the formula from my Javascript answer.

1. Precedence rules are weird. (at least I don't need to memorize too much, but it's counterintuitive)
2. More than half of the characters are BF keywords.
3. `-+>` and `:)`.