# Cartesian Coordinate Spiral

Tags: code-golf

## Challenge

Given an integer radius \$r \geq 0\$, write a program that prints each set of cartesian coordinates in a counter-clockwise spiral originating at \$(0, 0)\$ as shown here (for \$r = 3\$), with indices:

[image]

## Input

The program should take \$r\$, a non-negative integer, as an input. The input is assumed to be valid and in the range \$2^{32} \geq r \geq 0\$.

## Output

The output of the program should be a comma-space-delimited list of integer coordinates in a counter-clockwise circle, starting with \$(0, 0)\$ out to a radius of \$r\$.

## Test Cases

`r = 0` -> No output

`r = 1` ->

```
(0, 0)
```

`r = 3` (shown in diagram) ->

```
(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1), (2, -1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (0, 2), (-1, 2), (-2, 2), (-2, 1), (-2, 0), (-2 -1), (-2, 0), (-2, -1), (-2, -2), (-1, -2), (0, -2), (1, -2), (2, -2)
```

---

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes, per language, wins.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This is a very well written first challenge. However, I'm afraid it might be a dupe of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/87178/58563). The only notable difference is that the other challenge asks for one specific element.

Comment: @Arnauld ah, I didn't see that post when I searched for this one. Do you think this one is sufficiently different?

Comment: IMO, it's not different enough. But I won't VTC as dupe because my vote is a hammer. Let's see what others think.

Comment: So.... we are keeping this question open because our votes are hammers?

Comment: Since many people seem to agree that this is too close, I will hammer it. Generally I think if a question is just a "loop" of another one it should be closed. For the future, consider using our [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) so people can help catch this earlier. Still, a great first post! Hope you continue to post :)