# Placing circles along a square spiral

Tags: code-golf, sequence, geometry, packing

In this code golf challenge, you'll be computing the placement of ([open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics))) circles of areas \$\pi, 2\pi, 3\pi, \dots\$ when greedily placed along integer points in a square spiral in such a way that no two overlap.

A [square spiral](https://oeis.org/plot2a?name1=A174344&name2=A274923&tform1=untransformed&tform2=untransformed&shift=0&radiop1=xy&drawlines=true) is a sequence in \$\mathbb Z^2\$ that starts at \$(0,0)\$ and successively wraps around the origin. (Like [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222543/53884), you might find inspiration from [this CGSE question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/87178/53884).)

```
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 1) -> (0, 1) -> (-1, 1) -> (-1, 0) -> (-1, -1) -> (0, -1) -> (1, -1) -> (2, -1) -> (2, 0) -> (2, 1) -> (2, 2) -> (1, 2) -> (0, 2) -> (-1, 2) -> (-2, 2) -> (-2, 1) -> (-2, 0) -> (-2, -1) -> (-2, -2) -> (-1, -2) -> (0, -2) -> (1, -2) -> (2, -2) -> (3, -2) -> (3, -1) -> (3, 0) -> (3, 1) -> (3, 2) -> ...
```

[image: Example of a square spiral.]

---

In this challenge, you will start at the origin, walk around the spiral, and place circles with areas \$\pi, 2\pi, 3\pi\$, at integer points in a greedy fashion, as shown in the GIF below.

The first seven circles are:

- a circle of area \$\pi\$ placed at \$(0,0)\$,
- a circle of area \$2\pi\$ placed at \$(2,2)\$,
- a circle of area \$3\pi\$ placed at \$(-2,2)\$,
- a circle of area \$4\pi\$ placed at \$(3,-2)\$,
- a circle of area \$5\pi\$ placed at \$(-3,-3)\$,
- a circle of area \$6\pi\$ placed at \$(5,5)\$, and
- a circle of area \$7\pi\$ placed at \$(0,6)\$.

[image]

Again, the circles are placed as soon as they fit. The second circle could not be placed at \$(1,0)\$, \$(1,1)\$, \$(0,1)\$, \$(-1,1)\$, \$(-1,0)\$, \$(-1, -1)\$, \$(0,-1)\$, \$(1, -1)\$, \$(2, -1)\$, \$(2, 0)\$, or \$(2, 1)\$ without overlapping with the first circle, but it could be—and is—placed at \$(2,2)\$.

Once we've placed "all" of the blue circles, we start over. In the second generation, we place "red" circles with areas \$\pi, 2\pi, 3\pi\$, in a greedy fashion:

[image]

Once we've placed all of the red circles from the second generation, we move onto yellow circles, cyan circles, magenta, dark green, purple, light green, orange, brown circles, and so on.

[image: Process for ten generations]

## Challenge

Okay! That's a lot of setup! Here's your [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge:

Write a program that takes in two positive (alternatively, \$0\$-indexed) integers, `g` and `k`, and outputs the position of the circle of area \$k\pi\$ in the \$g\$-th generation.

When \$g=1\$, this corresponds to the blue circles; when \$g=2\$, this corresponds to the red circles; when \$g=3\$, the yellow circles, and so on.

Your program should be able to compute all of the values in the following table in practice, and it should be able to compute bigger values (without running into floating point errors) in principle.

#### Data table

```
 g |  k | position   | (color in GIFs; for reference only)
---+----+------------+------------------------------------
 1 |  1 | (0, 0)     | blue
 1 |  2 | (2, 2)     | blue
 1 |  3 | (-2, 2)    | blue
 1 | 50 | (36, -18)  | blue
 2 |  1 | (0, -4)    | red
 2 |  2 | (-3, 9)    | red
 2 | 14 | (-2, -59)  | red
 2 | 15 | (-66, 28)  | red
 3 |  1 | (-5, 2)    | yellow
 3 |  2 | (4, -10)   | yellow
 3 | 10 | (-58, 3)   | yellow
 8 |  1 | (-6, 10)   | orange
 8 |  2 | (16, 21)   | orange
 8 |  3 | (-27, -19) | orange
 9 |  1 | (-10, 6)   | crimson
 9 |  2 | (-25, 4)   | crimson
 9 |  3 | (17, -27)  | crimson
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this related to a problem of broader mathematical interest or just a fun puzzle?

Comment: @Jonah—just a puzzle! But I did publish an OEIS sequence back in 2017 about a related problem: [A289523](https://oeis.org/A289523).

Comment: Thank you for an interesting challenge! Little later I'd like post here full answer on Mathematica, may be not for real challenge, just for survey.
But for now I've found some intriguing detail:

`Input: RegionIntersection[Circle[{6,-6}, 3],Circle[{3,-2},2]  
Output: Point[{21/5,-(18/5)}]  `

So the question arose: should tangent circles be considered an overlap?
Looks like all answers here suppose "not" and include (6,-6).

Comment: @lesobrod—it's been a while since I've thought about this, but I think the circles should have radius \$\sqrt{3}\$ and \$\sqrt{2}\$ in order for their areas to be \$3\pi\$ and \$2\pi\$ respectively.

Comment: @PeterKagey These tangent circles have areas \$9 \pi\$ and \$4\pi\$     
Mathematica use `Circle[center_, radius_]`

Find them in a picture!

So  the question is stay open: should tangent circles be considered an overlap?

Comment: @lesobrod—That's two embarrassing oversights! I suppose to keep things consistent with how things have been, it's only fair to say that for the purposes of this challenge, tangent circles don't overlap. I've modified the question to specify "open" circles (which are, mathematically speaking, really open disks.) –

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 211 bytes

```javascript
g=>k=>{for(N=1;n=N;N*=2)for(G=g,C=[];G--;n-=r*3)for(o=[x=X=0,Y=y=s=1];x<n;o[[x+Y,y+X]]?0:[X,Y]=[Y,-X])if(!(o[[x+=X,y-=Y]]=C.some(([X,Y,R])=>Math.hypot(X-x,Y-y)<R+r,r=s**.5)||s++-k|G*C.push([x,y,r])))return[x,y]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc@xboMwEIDhvU/RbjbYKECRQp2jAwNTGTKBLA9RCiRNipFNKlDps9MkysaN9@n06@5r97Oze3Pset7qz2quYW4gOUHyW2tDcvBFC7nIHQjoDTJoWApSiYxz0XIwTnh3DXKAAlashBEs@EoMm1ZoKQe3ZKNbKPW@epMFKxXIkvFC0WNNXsh9AQo2ciiVgtSz@rsi5LbItopC8rHrD95h7HRPCj6wko90s3UNM2Adx4voNFnX5acpc1Kvu9gDkQMbmVGUUlP1F9PeZvU373Vr9bnyzrohNfEpefYpFU9LDnAOUY5WSw7wdoC3r@y/4hwtOcTbId6@so8cuMYjazyyxp@P8UiMR@JHZP4H)

- -3 bytes by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)

---

```javascript
g=>  // input: generation
k=>{ // input: circle area
for(
 N=1; // Search bound, we try to search generation 1
      // circles in [-N,N]x[-N,N]
 n=N; // Search bound of current generation
 N*=2 // If we cannot locate (g,k) circle
      // we try a larger bound later
)
 for(
  G=g, // Number of generation (count down)
  C=[]; // All Circles found yet
  G--; // Count down 1 generation
  // I'm not quite sure if next line is correct.
  // But it passes all testcases, at least.
  // Change to `n=n/4-r*4` would somehow ensure
  // its correctness, but also make it slow as hell.
  n-=r*3 // A smaller search bound for next generation
 )
  for(
   o=[ // All points visited, stored by key
       // For example, if (3, 4) is visited
       // o['3,4'] would be something truthy
    x= // Current x
    X=0, // Current x axis direction
    Y= // -Y is current y axis direction
    y= // current y
    s=1 // current circle area is s*PI
   ]; // Values initialized in Array o are harmless garbage
      // As index `0` or `1` is not in `x,y` format
   x<n; // Search in the bound
   o[[x+Y,y+X]]?0: // If the left side point is not visited
   [X,Y]=[Y,-X] // we turn left
  )
   if(!( // !(a||b) iff !a&&!b, known as De Morgan's laws
    o[
     [x+=X,y-=Y] // Move one step forward
    ]= // Mark current point visited
    // Is there a circle intersect with current one (if
    // we placed it here)?
    C.some(([X,Y,R])=>Math.hypot(X-x,Y-y)<R+r,r=s**.5)||
    // If no such circle, we need to place a circle here
    s++-k| // Is current area equals to user input `k`?
           // Increase the area for next circle by `s++`
           // `|` do not use short-circuit evaluation
    G* // Is current generation counted down to 0?
    C.push([x,y,r]) // Push it to list of circles
                    // C.push(...) always returns positive
                    // So multiply by G is harmless
   ))
    return[x,y] // Return current circle if it is asked for
}
```

Comment: Wow! Just when I thought I might win this if I keep golfing. How did you do this?

Comment: @Ausername added an explain to it.

Comment: @Ausername I didn't read your codes yet, since my brain give up to understand any golfed codes  written by others with more than 200 or 300 bytes, automatically.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by starting with `X=1`: [221 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc@xbsIwEIDhvU/RbnZyjkhSJFJzdGBgKgNTIssDCglQkI3sUCUiPHsaqm7ceJ@tX3ff25@tL93x0ghjd9VQ47DHxQkXt9o6tsZYGlzLdYAJf8AK97BEpeVKCGkEuiD98xYLnECOHXqMweLtLtu5kWXfL6PL1R@YaqEDBz4MNefHmr0xq6xSrSigE7nWn5MPlUOhURUwzjC@YA5diIXWyEpcRvXR7Bh7fIKN5rj42jaH6NBdbMNy0UIhOj7fhA4c@iCIppz3vRenfsW5q5qrM48N9H0orfH2XEVnu2c1izl7jTmXL8@c0JySPJ08c0K3E7o9cvxO8/SZU7qd0u2RY2LBGR2Z0ZEZfXxGRzI6kv1Hhl8)

Comment: @Arnauld Yes? but... I couldn't understand why it yield same results.

Comment: You just need to make sure that `-X` is used instead of `X` in all expressions.

Comment: @Arnauld ahh, got it.

Comment: @tsh I've added an explanation. At least I can still win "Most improved".

Comment: @Ausername But "Most Improved" is a prize for, you know, [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary)-like languages (x)

Comment: @tsh True. But you try writing a solution to this in Unary.

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES2020), <s>417</s> <s>338</s> <s>331</s> <s>323</s> <s>321</s> <s>318</s> <s>316</s> <s>304</s> <s>303</s> <s>290</s>  <s>283</s> <s>273</s> <s>269</s> <s>261</s> <s>257</s> <s>252</s> <s>247</s> <s>244</s> <s>237</s> <s>234</s> <s>238</s> <s>234</s> <s>207</s> <s>206</s> <s>205</s> <s>200</s> <s>194</s> <s>193</s> <s>186</s> <s>182</s> <s>183</s> 182 bytes

```javascript
G=>K=>eval('for(l=[];G--;)for(x=y=d=0,L=t=i=1,X=l[G]=[];t--,K<<3*G>=i;d%2?y+=2-d%4:x+=1-d%4,t||=L+=d++%2)X[l.some(Z=>Z.some(([M,N],R)=>Math.hypot(M-x,N-y)<R**.5+i**.5))||i++]=[x,y]')
```

[Try It Online?](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY7BasJAFEX3_Y_gvMxMMFFBmtwpXWWhceFKDFlIJ5rA6JQ6LQnkT7oJpf2F_kv_pgbduXnv3sPj3vf5fbK67L8q_Ly7vZz__aZQC6jyY2fYaG_fmEFexKmUMQ2uQQuNsVjCoUYoNjB5WgwnTkqxSJKJnyrUsfaip5YjktqbPjYc4SCE6zosOTTnXkSb3ARneyzZFmp7VSzPxKoQa4LKdq4KqvbVOpbJRqxkS8na94MZr4dJ1HU155fmRrTFiG7fP7_Y09maMjD2wCoWEQunRA_3dHZHJxc6pltQ31_3Pw)

Severely golfed. Very inefficient. Thanks to @Neil for getting rid of all the spare bytes I had lying around, and @tsh for removing a lot more. Takes G 1-indexed and K 1-indexed. -1 byte thanks to ophact.

Somehow beat @Arnauld, <s>but still losing to @tsh by a lot</s> somehow outgolfed tsh as well.

## Explanation

Slightly different to actual code.

```javascript
G =>                         // A function taking G (generation)
K => {                       // and K (circle number)
  for(                       // Start a loop...
    l = [];                  // l = 2d list of circles we've already found, starts empty
    G--;                     // Looping G times...
  )                          
    for(                     // Another loop
                             // Initialise some variables
      x = y =                // x, y = current coordinates in the spiral
      d = 0                  // d = direction of current leg of spiral, initialise them all to 0
      t =                    // t = distance to end of spiral
      i =                    // i = current radius
      L = 1,                 // L = total length of current leg of spiral
      X = l[G] = [];         // Add an empty list to l, which gets assigned to X.
      t--,
      K << 3 * G >= i;       // Every generation, search for 8x less circles (probably enough, can always be increased)              
      d % 2 ?                // If moving vertically
        y += 2 - d % 4       // Change y
      : x += 1 - d % 4,      // Else change x
      t ||=                  // If t is falsy, set t to...
      L +=                   // L incremented by...
      d++ % 2                // direction modulo 2
    ) 
    l.some(                      // Do any values in l have the property that...
      Z=>Z.some(                 // Any of their values have the property that...
        ([M,N],R) =>             // (M, N = coords, R = radius)
        Math.hypot(M - x, N - y) // Is the distance to the point we're on right now...
        < R ** .5 + i ** .5      // Less than the sum of their radii?
      )
    ) ? 0 :                      // If not, we can place a circle.
    X[i++] = [x,y]               // Increment i (radius of circle we're trying to place), and append the coordinate to X
                                 // The above is returned when the loop ends because i is too large.
}
```

Comment: I got it down to 338: `h=(G,K,l=[],p=[],x=y=t=P=d=0,i=w=L=1,a=([...Array(5e4)].map(_=>p.push([x,y])+(d?d<2?y++:d<3?x--:y--:x++,++t==L&&(t=0,++P>1&&(L++,P=0))+(d=(d+1)%4)))))=>[...Array(G)].map(_=>p.map(x=>l.map(y=>((y[0]-x[0])**2+(y[1]-x[1])**2)**.5<y[2]**.5+i**.5?k=0:0,k=1)+(k&&(l.push([x[0],x[1],i,w]),i++)))+(w++,i=1))?l.filter(x=>x[3]==G)[K-1].slice(0,2):0`

Comment: Not sure why `((y[0]-x[0])**2+(y[1]-x[1])**2)**.5` isn't the same as `Math.hypot(y[0]-x[0],y[1]-x[1])` though.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for all of that! Managed to golf it down a bit more. You're right, `((y[0]-x[0])**2+(y[1]-x[1])**2)**.5` is the same as `Math.hypot(y[0]-x[0],y[1]-x[1])`.

Comment: @tsh Thanks for that!

Comment: @tsh You are too good at this.

Comment: @tsh Wow. Just wow.

Comment: The thing is, switching to `Math.hypot` changes the output for `2,2` from `-2,10` to `-3,9`... wait, it was supposed to be that all along! D'oh!

Comment: @Neil I'm not sure what is up with that. Math.hypot does exactly that - maybe it handles floats differently or something...

Comment: -1 byte by evaluating `for` and removing `return`: `G=>K=>eval('for(l=[],w=1;w<=G;)for(x=y=d=0,t=i=L=1,X=l[w++]=[];t--<250;t||=L+=d++%2)l.some(Z=>Z.some(([M,N],R)=>Math.hypot(M-x,N-y)<++R**.5+i**.5))?0:X[i++-1]=[x,y],d%2?y+=2-d%4:x+=1-d%4;X[K]')`. Works on all cases

Comment: @ophact Nice lol

Comment: "Your program should be able to compute all of the values in the following table in practice" Does it do all tests, maybe in one day?

Comment: @l4m2 Missed that.

Comment: @l4m2 Actually, for the maximal case it's computing around 3*8^8 = 48 million circles for the first layer. I'd say that's feasible on a sufficiently powerful computer.

Comment: 48M circles, each taking 48M area(ignoring pi/2), it's 2Peta points to test

Comment: and each point test 48M existing circles, it's too much work

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>319</s>  309 bytes

Expects `(g)(k)` and returns `[x,y]`.

The formula for the spiral coordinates was inspired by [this answer from Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87394/58563).

```javascript
g=>k=>{a=[];p=[];r=[];H=Math.hypot;F=n=>{while((j=p[n]=-~p[n],C=_=>((i+2>>2)-i%2*j)*~-(i--&2),x=C(i=(--j*4+1)**.5|0,j-=i*i>>2),y=C(),n)&&a.every(([N,X,Y])=>~N+n|H(X,Y)<2*H(x,y))&&!F(n-1,p[n]--)||a.some(([_,X,Y,R])=>H(X-x,Y-y)<R**.5+q**.5,q=-~r[n]));a.push([n,x,y,r[n]=q])};while(~~r[g-1]<k)F(g-1);return[x,y]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNb4JAEIbv/RX0UDODOyiLmDa4XEyMl/bgqYYQQywqaBfEj0qq/nW7m1ZTK73MfuR5d57ZNNpGq3GR5GuS2Vt8mojTVPhz4X9GIgi9XJdCl754jtYza1bm2drrCamIj1myiAFSkQcyFHTUC@uKkfABkjr3fY6UPHAzRfNIkBDVOLKd6EIigCg1W3UbTdNy902WkkjMRCdYqQBkEmu1yIq3cVECBC/slQ1DFP7xpS73fVAn7HCzDztWoiLveyDJZlqACPf7yFpl70otGOkgG@ioStGODanEzkB3rS91ZUslXqgcohdZ@WY1g0Ay9SzTl2IZ4sH7nvOosCnZYWeOPVAb9Ip4vSlkoODwcBpncpUtYmuRTWECNoJhIxqNhgGG0WSGKnh3y/ALwzXDqxjnzNC/jNs8M06bGWQ//mX4jQ@1qpiLDzm611MFY7eufNxKxv1hqK18DH7j4/z2IbdyLufqf1p6riaevgA)

#### How?

One tricky point in the challenge is to figure out how many circles of generation \$n-1\$ must be processed before we can start generation \$n\$.

In this implementation, we don't attempt to put a new circle of generation \$n\$ at \$(x_0,y_0)\$ until there's at least one circle of generation \$n-1\$ at \$(x_1,y_1)\$ which is at least twice as far from the center of the spiral:

$$\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{y_1}^2}\ge2\times \sqrt{{x_0}^2+{y_0}^2}$$